# How do I put a String into an array and then into an array of double?

Tags: java, arrays, double, sequences

Currently I have this:

```
public class sequence
{
private double[] sequence; 
// set up sequence by parsing s
//the numbers in s will be seperated by commas
public Sequence(String s)
{
  String [] terms = s.split (",");
  sequence = Double.parseDouble(terms);
}
}
```

What I have does not work. But basically what i am trying to achieve is to move the numerical terms in String s (such as 1,2,3,4,5,6) in an array of double called sequence.

Comment: If you say, that it doesn't work, you should describe how it behaves. You can [edit] your question to include this detail.

Comment: You can't parse an array of doubles. Only one double at a time. So iterate over the `String` array and convert each element into a double and add it to your double array manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double.parseDouble` take one `String` and returns one `Double`.
You are passing an array of Strings.
Change you code to pass just one String.

```
public Sequence(String s) {
    String [] terms = s.split (",");
    sequence = new Double[terms.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
        sequence[i] = Double.parseDouble(terms[i]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the terms.

```
String [] terms = s.split (",");
sequence = new double[terms.length];
for (int i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    sequence[i] = Double.parseDouble(terms[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can do something like

```
double[] sequence = Stream.of(s.split(",")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
```